# Clarification on classes and scopes in this scenario

Tags: c++, juce

I'm currently working with the JUCE Framework to create an audio VST plugin to get to grips and learn, but just want to clarify some basic stuff relating to classes.

in my header file, i have a class `EQPLUGProcessor` and inside that class i call `static juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout createParameterLayout();`

When i call the function `createParameterLayout()` in my .cpp i have to write `juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout EQPLUGAudioProcessor::createParameterLayout(){}`

My question is, why do i have to include the  `juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout` before the actual scope that the function is in ( `EQPLUGAudioProcessor`)? Surely i should be telling the compiler to look in the  `EQPLUGAudioProcessor` and thats it?

I get that `EQPLUGAudioProcessor` is the class which its all inside, but still cant seem to understand when, where and why i'd need to clarify the classes that the function comes from *again* in the .cpp?

Let me know if this requires clarification.

Comment: These seem to be freecodecamp's one of the latest video right

Comment: All this follows the definition of the C++ language. Still, I'm not sure what your question is. Maybe you could give an example of how you have to write code and then how you would prefer to write the code instead?

Comment: @Agent_A That's correct yeah, i come from an audio engineer background so designing my own VST's is of great interest to me as an initial project. Really enjoying it so far!

Comment: I'll surely check that video as soon as my pc gets repaired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enclosing namespace or a class does not have to be specified ***only inside the same namespace or a class***:

```
class store {

    class give_me {

    // ...

    };

    static give_me something_cool();
};
```

Here, the declaration of `something_cool`() only needs to reference `give_me`, rather than `store::give_me`. This is because this declaration appears ***inside the declaration*** of its class.

Now that this class is declared, and it's time to define it's class method, everything must be spelled out:

```
store::give_me store::something_cool()
{
      // ...
}
```

If the class method returned a `void` instead you'l ***still*** have to write something like:

```
void store::something_cool()
{
      // ...
}
```

You already understand that you can't just write `void something_cool`() and define this class method. This would only define some unrelated function with this name.

You have to write `store::something_cool` because this definition no longer appears within the `store` scope.

Well, the same thing applies not just to class methods but also to inner classes (and also other kinds of symbols that are declared in some enclosing scope). Since `give_me` is not a class that's declared in global scope, it is an inner class, when in global scope you must reference it as `store::give_me`.

That's just how C++ works. There are also various complicated rules that define where a scope begins, and ends, with respect to C++'s syntax, that's tangentially related to this. In some cases it is possible to take advantage of these scoping rules and avoding explicit scope references by using an `auto` declaration with a trailing return type; but how to do that will have to be a different question for some other time.